# Custom format for list output in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've reviewed other questions and haven't found this answer specifically.
I'm making a program to read a text file with multiple rows of data, and to quantify similar rows.
Below is my code that I have working, but I'm trying to have the output in a custom format, or at least printed individually. How can I improve on that?

Ideally I'd like an output like:

```
B12-H-BB-DD: x3
A2-W-FF-DIN: x2
A2-FF-DIN: x1
C1-GH-KK-LOP: x1
```

```
import collections
a = "test.txt"
line_file = open(a, "r")
print(line_file.readable()) #Readable check.
print(line_file.read()) #Prints each individual line.

#Code for quantity counter.
counts = collections.Counter() #Creates a new counter.
with open(a) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        for number in line.split():
            counts.update((number,))
print(counts) #How can I print these on separate lines, with custom format?

line_file.close()
```

Comment: As a quick option, you can use `pprint.pprint()`. For more detailed printing, you'd have to iterate over the items (key-value pairs) and print them the way you want, for example: `for key, value in counts.items(): print(key, value)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
counts = {}
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        counts[line] = counts.get(line, 0) + 1

print(counts)
```

`counts.get(line, 0)` returns `0` if given key does not exist yes in the result dictionary.

Output:

```
{'B12-H-BB-DD': 3, 'A2-W-FF-DIN': 2, 'A2-FF-DIN': 1, 'C1-GH-KK-LOP': 1}
```

Special formating:

```
for key, count in counts.items():
    print(f"{key}: x{count}")
```

Output:

```
B12-H-BB-DD: x3
A2-W-FF-DIN: x2
A2-FF-DIN: x1
C1-GH-KK-LOP: x1
```

More Pythonic way using Counter from collections:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('file.txt') as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f]
counts = Counter(lines)

for key, count in counts.items():
    print(f"{key}: x{count}")
```